# How to use multiple values in between clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi all is there any way that i can use multiple values in between clause as 
column_name between 0 and 100 or 200 and 300 like this 
Any help would be appreciated
here is my query `SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(value_text) = 1 THEN CAST(value_text AS INT) ELSE -1 END) between  0 and 100`
i just want to append multiple values in between clause

This is full query

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
  (
        order by Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID asc
  )AS RowNumber
  , Unit_Table.Unit_title, Vendor_Base_Price.Base_Price, Vendor_Base_Price.showprice, Category_Table.Title, Vendor_Registration.Business_Name, 
                     Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Street_Address, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Locality, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Nearest_Landmark, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.City, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.State, 
                     Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Country, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.PostalCode, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Latitude, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Longitude, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.ImageUrl, 
                     Vendor_PrimaryInfo.ContactNo, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Email,Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID


  FROM  Unit_Table INNER JOIN
                     Vendor_Base_Price ON Unit_Table.Unit_ID = Vendor_Base_Price.Unit_ID INNER JOIN
                     Vendor_PrimaryInfo ON Vendor_Base_Price.Vendor_ID = Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID INNER JOIN
                     Vendor_Registration ON Vendor_Base_Price.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID AND 
                     Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID INNER JOIN
                     Category_Table ON Vendor_Registration.Category_ID = Category_Table.Category_ID
                     LEFT JOIN
                     Vendor_Value_Table ON Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Value_Table.Vendor_ID LEFT JOIN
                     Feature_Table ON Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID = Feature_Table.Feature_ID

                 where Vendor_Registration.Category_ID=5 and Vendor_PrimaryInfo.City='City'
                  AND(
  value_text in('Dhol Wala$Shahnai Wala') 
  or 
 (SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(value_text) = 1 THEN CAST(value_text AS INT) ELSE -1 END) between  0 and 100 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `AND/OR` logic

```
value_text NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' and 
(
value_text between 0 and 100
Or 
value_text between 101 and 200
)
```

If you don't want to repeat the column name then frame the range in table valued constructor and join with your table

```
SELECT Row_number()
         OVER (
           ORDER BY Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID ASC )AS RowNumber,
       Unit_Table.Unit_title,
       Vendor_Base_Price.Base_Price,
       Vendor_Base_Price.showprice,
       Category_Table.Title,
       Vendor_Registration.Business_Name,
       Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Street_Address,
       Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Locality,
       Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Nearest_Landmark,
       Vendor_PrimaryInfo.City,
       Vendor_PrimaryInfo.State,
       Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Country,
       Vendor_PrimaryInfo.PostalCode,
       Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Latitude,
       Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Longitude,
       Vendor_PrimaryInfo.ImageUrl,
       Vendor_PrimaryInfo.ContactNo,
       Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Email,
       Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID
FROM   Unit_Table
       INNER JOIN Vendor_Base_Price
               ON Unit_Table.Unit_ID = Vendor_Base_Price.Unit_ID
       INNER JOIN Vendor_PrimaryInfo
               ON Vendor_Base_Price.Vendor_ID = Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID
       INNER JOIN Vendor_Registration
               ON Vendor_Base_Price.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID
                  AND Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID
       INNER JOIN Category_Table
               ON Vendor_Registration.Category_ID = Category_Table.Category_ID
       LEFT JOIN Vendor_Value_Table
              ON Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Value_Table.Vendor_ID
       LEFT JOIN Feature_Table
              ON Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID = Feature_Table.Feature_ID
       JOIN (VALUES (0, 100),
                    (101, 200),
                    (201, 300)) tc (st, ed)
         ON Try_cast(value_text AS INT) BETWEEN st AND ed
             OR Try_cast(value_text AS VARCHAR(100)) = 'Dhol Wala$Shahnai Wala'
WHERE  Vendor_Registration.Category_ID = 5
       AND Vendor_PrimaryInfo.City = 'City'
```

**Note :** You have stored two different information's in a single column which causes lot of pain when you want to extract the data like this. Consider changing your table structure

Comment: i dont want to use column name multiple time just between and or

Comment: Can u please elaborate your example with my query

Comment: SELECT *
  From Vendor_Value_Table
WHERE (Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID in (17,19)) 
AND(
value_text in('Dhol Wala$Shahnai Wala') 
or 
 (SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(value_text) = 1 THEN CAST(value_text AS INT) ELSE -1 END) between  0 and 100 
 )

Comment: now it is giving error because some values are nvarchar type so it fails in conversion

Comment: @user1870546 which version of sql server you are using

Comment: I m using sql server 2012

Comment: @user1870546 - check now

Comment: I used CAST in place of TRY_CONVERT because its giving error near AS and after doing that error comes 
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Dhol Wala$Shahnai Wala' to data type int.

Comment: @user1870546 - yeah missed to add `TRY_CAST` to another filter. Check now added.

Comment: it works with the query u provided for the single table but actually is the part of main query in which i have to add condition with and so how would i do that?

Comment: @user1870546 - then post the main query and tell where it should be added. Plus that would be a new question

Comment: this is the procedure where i have to append the query with and DECLARE return_value int,
  RecordCount int

EXEC return_value = [dbo].[vendorlist]
  PageIndex = 1,
  PageSize = 10,
  type = N'5',
  city = N'Kanpur',
  query = N' and (Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID in (17,19)) 
AND(
value_text like ''Dhol Wala$Shahnai Wala'' 
OR 
 (SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(value_text) = 1 THEN CAST(value_text AS INT) ELSE -1 END) between 0 and 100
 )',
  RecordCount = RecordCount OUTPUT

SELECT RecordCount as N'RecordCount'

SELECT 'Return Value' = return_value

GO

Comment: @user1870546 stop posting queries in comments section. Add it in question with what has to be done

Comment: I added the full query sorry for inconvenience please help

Comment: @user1870546 - added full query in my answer

Comment: @user1870546 - You need to ask a new question with Sample data and expected result alond with this query. This question started with some other request now it some where else

Comment: ok i m marking this thread as solved thanks for you time really appreciate it

Comment: i created a  new thread can u help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062927/how-to-supply-multiple-values-in-between-clause-after-where-clause