# How to supply multiple values in between clause after where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID ASC) AS RowNumber, 
    *
FROM  
    Unit_Table 
INNER JOIN
    Vendor_Base_Price ON Unit_Table.Unit_ID = Vendor_Base_Price.Unit_ID 
INNER JOIN
    Vendor_PrimaryInfo ON Vendor_Base_Price.Vendor_ID = Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID 
INNER JOIN
    Vendor_Registration ON Vendor_Base_Price.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID 
                        AND Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID 
INNER JOIN
    Category_Table ON Vendor_Registration.Category_ID = Category_Table.Category_ID
LEFT JOIN
    Vendor_Value_Table ON Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Value_Table.Vendor_ID 
LEFT JOIN
    Feature_Table ON Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID = Feature_Table.Feature_ID
WHERE
    Vendor_Registration.Category_ID = 5 
    AND Vendor_PrimaryInfo.City = 'City'
    AND (value_text in ('sample value') or 
         (SELECT 
              CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(value_text) = 1 
                      THEN CAST(value_text AS INT)   
                      ELSE -1 
              END) BETWEEN 0 AND 100)
```

As column has multiple values which may be text or may be int that's why I cast based on case. My question is: I just want to fetch the records either whose value is between 0 and 100 or value between 300 to 400 or value is like sample value.

I just want to place the condition after where clause and do not want to use column_name multiple time in between operator because these values are coming from url

Thanks in advance any help would be grateful.

Comment: You want another condition as between 100-200 ? For 300-400 ?

Comment: @AmirZiarati yes conditions being appended as need like between 300 and 400 or 400 or 500 and so on and also dont want to use value_text column multiple times

Comment: This kinda of action means dynamic query. This needs to be done at the code side. For example if your coding asp.net you need to make a dynamic query and appen to that if you need. For example if you need another betweeen or 3 other betweens you make a for loop and append your new conditions to the query and then run the quru

Comment: @AmirZiarati yes i understand but how can i use it here, here i have to write value_text between 0 and 100 or value_text between 300 and 500 and so on but i do not want to use value_text column name multiple times, like if i want to use in text i just simply write where value_text IN ('v1','V2',....) so is there any way in between clause?

Comment: These questiona are so damn basic. Look at this: string query = "select * from table t where id="+ yourVariable.   I just built an simple query with a changeable condition. yourVariable can be changed to any ID. So simple.

Comment: @AmirZiarati I am asking that is there any way to perform query like where column_name IN between ('0 and 100' , '300 or 400' and so on) later on i will provide these value from code behind

Comment: @AmirZiarati see the code and suggest where i put second between values without using column name again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way..

```
WHERE
    Vendor_Registration.Category_ID = 5 
    AND Vendor_PrimaryInfo.City = 'City'
    AND (value_text in ('sample value') or 
         (CASE WHEN (ISNUMERIC(value_text) = 1)
                      THEN CAST(value_text AS INT)   
                      ELSE -1 
              END) BETWEEN 0 AND 100)
```

Comment: then how i can pass next value in between operator here?

Comment: Removed (( and replaced with single ( before ISNUMERIC function